# Pass props via forwardRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component named 'Timeline', and inside of that component, a have a button that on it's onClick, call a method named `handleSpeed(e)`, that method send on its properties, the speed that the user set on the button to change the speed of a player, just like that.

```js
        <Button  onClick={(() => handleSpeed(2))}>2x</Button>
```

The problem is, my player is another component, and need to send the speed set on my button, to my component. Here is how I'm doing that:

1. I've a button and, its button send the speed via onClick:

```js
        <Button  onClick={(() => handleSpeed(2))}>2x</Button>
```

2. After that, i've a method who send the speed to the component, of the player:

```js
     function handleSpeed(e) {
         if (onSpeed) onSpeed(e);
         // console.log('onspeed set dentro da timeline velocidade igual a: ', e)
         return e
       }
```

3. The onspeed, is a propertie of my timeline component, that send the speed set to my parent component, and that speed, is received like that:

```js
     function setSpeed(e) {
         const recordSpeed = get(recordRef, "current.setSpeed", e)
         recordSpeed()
       }
```

4. The problem is, my player component, take the actions like, play, pause, resume, stop, via ref, using forwardRef, here is a exemple of the play action:

```js
     play: () => {
               if (replayerRef.current) {
                 if (pauseTimeOffset) {
                   return replayerRef.current.resume(pauseTimeOffset);
                 }
                 replayerRef.current.play();          
               }
             },
```

5. I want to take the speed, that is passed via properties of my button, to my player component, but, somehow, i can't do that cause, i'm doing it like that:

```js
     function setSpeed(e){
           replayerRef.current.config.speed = e;
         }
```

6. My 'e' comes undefined.

Do you know, a way to me take the speed sent via onClick and, recieve that speed in my player component, without changing the structure of my components?

Comment: Can you post your code on codesanbox.io?

Comment: Unfortunately the code have a lot of dependencies, and it will not work on that.

Comment: What about using React context or some kind of store management (ie: Redux) instead of `forwardRef`?

Comment: I just put the code on: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cori-31pph?file=/src/Player.tsx

Comment: Your codesandbox doesn't work.

Comment: It's because the number of dependencies that my code have, maybe seeing the code, you know how to help me to take the value from setSpeed props